# You are racing around a circular track $C$...

Tags: trigonometry

> You are racing around a circular track $C$; the pits are at a point $P$ on the circumference of $C$. Your car is equally likely to break down at any point $B$ of the track. Let $X$ be the distance from $B$ to $P$ in a straight line. Find the density, mean, and variance of $X$.

Let the track have radius $a$ and
suppose I let $P = (a,0)$ and $B= (a\cos(\theta), a\sin(\theta))$. $PB = (a\cos(\theta)-a, a\sin(\theta)).$

That is, $X = |PB| = \sqrt{2}a(1-\cos(\theta))^{\frac{1}{2}}$. According to the solutions the answer is $X = 2a \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$. I don't understand how to get to this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done thus far is correct.

We can use the identity
$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{1 - \cos\theta}{2}$$
If $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, then $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \geq 0$.  Hence,
$$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{2}}$$
Thus,
$$\sqrt{1 - \cos\theta} = \sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
Therefore,
$$X = |PB| = a\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1 - \cos\theta} = a\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = 2a\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$